# My light-dm greeter only quickly shows my wallpaper then changes to the default one

Tags: debian, lightdm, wallpaper

I am trying to let the login greeter of my Debian unstable machine show a custom wallpaper. It shows up quickly at boot, like half a second but then it fades into the default wallpaper.
What could be the reason?

Here is how I configured it and some info about my machine:

```
> sudo cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf | ag -v \#

[greeter]
background=/usr/share/wallpaper/leaf.png

ls -lisah /usr/share/wallpaper/leaf.png 
18350307 1,8M -rw-rw-rw- 1 foo foo 1,8M 10. Jul 08:51 /usr/share/wallpaper/leaf.png

> apt info lightdm

Package: lightdm
Version: 1.26.0-8

> apt info lightdm-gtk-greeter

Package: lightdm-gtk-greeter
Version: 2.0.8-2+b1

> uname -a && lsb_release -a

Linux foo 5.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.5-1 (2022-06-16) x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid
Release:        unstable
Codename:       sid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem and I managed to solve it by adding:

```
user-background=false
```

so the full file looks like this:

```
[greeter]
background=/usr/share/wallpaper/leaf.png
user-background=false
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! :)